# iOS, re-use AppIcon in assets catalog in my LaunchScreen Storyboard?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard, asset-catalog

I'd like to show my app icon in my `launch storyboard`.

I've added a `UIImageView` and I can select other images in my `asset catalog`, they are shown in the `dropdown`. However `AppIcon` is not.

I've tried to trick `interface builder` and specify the image name directly but that doesn't work either.

I'm guess it can't be reused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppIcon files can, in fact, be reused. If you drag a specific file to the Copy Bundle Resources build phase, the icon files will be usable without taking up more space.